# mysql where in from field multiple value

Tags: mysql

I have table `region` with fields

`id` | `name` | `dates`

**Sample data**

> 1 | local | "2018-01-01", "2018-01-02", "2018-01-03"

I want a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM region WHERE "2018-01-02" in (region.dates)
```

but this does not work. I do not use json data in this case. How can I change it?

Comment: I believe your schema requires some [restructuring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) if you need to that!

Answer (score 1):

(My)SQL doesn't work like that as it will see `region.dates` as a simple string. In which case, you can do `SELECT * FROM region WHERE dates LIKE '%"2018-01-02"%';`

However, a better solution would be to devolve that column into another table.

Comment: nice for tricky i just add code to find by column WHERE region.dates LIKE CONCAT("%", date_format(other.created_at, "%m-%d-%Y") ,"%")